# Co-registration on two different sites

Tags: php, forms, submit, auto-registration

I'm trying to do co-registration, *i.e.* register on the original site first, then register the same form values to an external site.

I am looking for a clear way to do it, but without displaying an additional form with the values already populated.

I could get the form values from the original form using the following, but I am not sure it is the best way of doing it.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'JSON',
  data: {param1: $('input#param1').val(), param2: $('input#param2').val()},
  url: 'url to post to',
  success: (your success callback function goes here)
})
```

Really I just wanted to know if there is another way, but since all I have from the other site is the URL to send the data, jQuery is the only way I can think of — just want to know if anyone has another way of doing it seamlessly, without jQuery?

Comment: That's interesting. Could you provide us with the code you're using? Or are you just looking for us to do your research/work for you?

Comment: Seems like you are obviously waiting to down vote posts :) and take your rudeness for as kindness :)

Comment: I can actually code php, jquery and coldfusion and the rest but like everyone else I know I don't know everything.

Comment: No. Please don't be mistaken, it wasn't rude, nor was it kind. It was a direct result of your poorly written question asking for us to do the work for you. You may be new here, so let me help you out: `Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results`, [StackOverflow checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Please familiarize yourself with that meta.

Comment: I know this can me accomplished using jQuery ajax but just wondering if someone has done it with php a before?

Comment: Yes, they have done it with PHP before.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy is right. You need to try to do it first. Then come to us if you encounter a specific problem.

Comment: If you register on the original site first, that would mean you have all the data you need. Why not copy that data in to the database of the other site, instead of opening another form (if that is what you're trying to do?)

Comment: I was not asking you to do research for me. If you don't have a clue of how to get it done so instead of a down-vote ignore it and move on.

Comment: Down vote's are not meant as an insult but as a way of making you realise there is something lacking with the question, don't take it personally ;)

Comment: @Bono yes I have the data submited from the first site. I guess the jQuery code is the only way to do it then?

Comment: @KwasiBrown Does the data _need_ to be inserted into another form? Or is that just a way of how you think it should work? If it is not a requirement you could just simply use the original data to insert it into 2 different databases (the original one, and the one from the other site). If it is required however, there are a couple of ways to transfer the values. jQuery could be one of them, depending on what you can use you could try PHP, JSON etc.

Comment: A down vote doesn't mean we don't know how to do it. It means you've asked a bad question. We're trying to help you write a better question so that it doesn't get closed and you're being rude.

Comment: You could also try [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). cURL allows you to post data to another site in the same way you would post it from a form... but without the form.

Comment: @Bono I don't have access to the external database so otherwise it would have taken me 5 minutes to do it :)

Comment: @Herbert thanks for the cURL idea that might be what I am looking for I'll try and give it a go!

Comment: @KwasiBrown sorry, just saw your edit ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your situation is similar to the scenario in this tutorial: [Execute a HTTP POST Using PHP CURL](http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post). Also see the first comment on that page which may or may not be relevent here:

> Your idea is simple enough tho if you’re going to be continually
>   working with this remote database with limited access (are you working
>   with a 3rd party?) you might want to use something a little more
>   standard like SOAP or REST so that you can have error checking, etc.

Since you didn't give any details about your specific needs, I can't give any code that's relevant to your situation.

Comment: I was not really looking for code was just another idea how to get it done without db access.
thanks you!

Comment: You're welcome. In ref to your comment on @Josh's answer: Apparently _this_ question has been answered, but if you try it and have problems that you **tried to fix, but couldn't**, feel free to open _another_ question. Furthermore, it's customary to accept (big red checkmark next to) the answer that helped you the most and upvote good answers. Welcome to StackOverflow. Hope you enjoy your stay. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try cURL:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/page?variable1='.$variable1.'&variable2='.$variable2);
$return = curl_exec($ch);
```

This should allow you to dynamically build a URL string that contains all of the variables for submitting to the registration page at the second location.

Comment: Thank you for the code.
 @Herbert yes I need to use post so thanks for the tutorial I'll update the question when I get it working :)